# Can I reset the commit history from a forked repo?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently starting a new project based on a previous one .
I forked it and now I'm cleaning up the parts I don't need.

The issue is that a forked project keeps the commit history and bring the starting date of the base repo.

I would like the repo to look like it was a brand new project.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Yes. Just delete the `.git` folder and start a new repo from the current working tree with `git init`.

Comment: @RomainValeri Deleting the `.git` removes carefully crafted `.git/config` and clever tricks in `.git/hooks`. Deleting the `.git`  seldom is the answer. See the duplicate for more interesting approaches.

Comment: @phd I missed that question, I admit it's a way more comprehensive approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: You can simply check the repo out locally, remove the (usually hidden) `.git` folder from like so :

```
rm -rf .git
```

and create a new repo.

Alternatively, you can rebase the entire history into one giant squash commit, but that'll be more work if you really are just interested in a single fork-is-base commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the .git folder and reinit the repo